# Can't get login success to view

Tags: php

so I've put in the write credentials to the login form, and it's supposed to redirect me to the home.php page which displays a successful login, however when I hit submit, the page just refreshes and doesn't do anything. If I change what the login_action loads after login it does it right, but then if I tell it to load home.php it just does nothing....Any Help?

Here's my home.php code:

```
<?php

session_start() ;

if( !isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    require('login_tools.php');
    load();         
}

$page_title = 'Home';

echo"<h1>HOME</h1>
<p>You are now logged in, {$_SESSION['username']}</p>";

echo'<p><a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a></p>';

?>
```

and the login_action.php

```
   <?php

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
require ('../connect_db.php') ;
require ('login_tools.php') ;

list ($check, $data) = 
validate($dbc, $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

if ($check )
{
 session_start() ;

 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'] ;
 $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'] ;

 load('home.php') ;
}
else {$errors = $data ;}

mysqli_close( $dbc);
}

include('login.php'); 
?>

**login.php:**


 <?php

$page_title = 'Login';

if ( isset( $errors ) && !empty( $errors))
{
echo'<p id="err_msg">Oops! There was a problem:<br>';
foreach ( $errors as $msg )
{
    echo " - $msg<br>";
}
echo 'Please try again or <a href="register.php">Register</a></p>';
}
?>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="login_action.php" method="POST">
<p>
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
</p><p>
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
</p><p>
<input type="submit" value="Login" >
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the code of your login form?

Comment: @sємsєм, hah, sorry. Done.

Comment: @sємsєм I tried seperating it from login_action but i couldn't work out how...

Comment: Just get extra one new line and select every part alone then apply code tool `{}`.

Comment: user 'header` like `header('Location: home.php')`

Comment: "when I hit submit, the page just refreshes and doesn't do anything" .. does it mean that it successfully login?

Comment: I don't know, because the page I set up to show me, home.php isn't appearing at all. Also, the error message for the password and username not found doesn't show either

Answer (score 0):

According to your code it is supposed to refresh. Indeed, it is not a refresh, it is the infinite loading of `login.php` by include it in the end of `login_action.php`

You should use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect instead of including as follows:

```
    <?php
    $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
    require ('../connect_db.php') ;
    require ('login_tools.php') ;

    list ($check, $data) = 
    validate($dbc, $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

    if ($check )
    {
     session_start() ;

     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'] ;
     $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'] ;

     $extra = 'home.php';
    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
    }
    else {
    $errors = $data ;
    $_SESSION['Errors'] = $errors;
    $extra = 'login.php';
    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
    exit;
    }

    mysqli_close( $dbc);
    }


    ?>
```

In login.php

```
$page_title = 'Login';

    if ( isset( $_SESSION['Errors'] ) && !empty( $_SESSION['Errors'])){
    $errors = $_SESSION['Errors'];
    //continue your code...
    // at the end of the code:
    unset($_SESSION['Errors']);
```

Comment: I changed the login_action.php script to this, and now I'm not getting any error messages for when I input incorrect credentials...and it's still just refreshing the page

Comment: As a side hint: try to learn a template engine, such as [tag:twig]

Comment: i.e `$_SESSION['Errors'] = $errors` so you could use it in the login page again if it was set. Something similar to `$_SESSION['username']` but don't forget to unset it in the login page after using it in displaying error meassge.

Comment: Now I'm getting these errors: Notice: Undefined variable: errors in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\login.php on line 9

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\login.php on line 9
Please try again or Register


Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\login.php on line 14

Comment: You have a typo. Read the warning message carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply, i guess session doesn't get anything to load home. It is from:

```
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'] ;
 $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'] ;
```

this makes validate get unvalidated to send the session.

Try to change the $data into variables, as follows:

```
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id ;
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username ;
```

to show the message, you can use meta refresh to encertain that it really sends the login data.
If this not works, there must be something wrong with the grabbing data from the connection.

Comment: Hiya, I made the correction above, and I am still getting the refresh of the login.php page. Even with correct/incorrect credentials. Also, if I remove the home.php code and replace it with a h1 tag it redirects successfully, so is the fault in the home.php code or another place? Any help would be appreciated, this is setting back my schedule quite substantially.

Comment: what login_tools.php looks like. let me know pls.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php # LOGIN HELPER FUNCTIONS.

# Function to load specified or default URL.
function load( $page = 'login.php' )
{
  # Begin URL with protocol, domain, and current directory.
  $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . dirname( $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ) ;

  # Remove trailing slashes then append page name to URL.
  $url = rtrim( $url, '/\\' ) ;
  $url .= '/' . $page ;

  # Execute redirect then quit. 
  header( "Location: $url" ) ; 
  exit() ;
}

# Function to check email address and password. 
function validate( $dbc, $email = '', $pwd = '')
{
  # Initialize errors array.
  $errors = array() ; 

  # Check email field.
  if ( empty( $email ) ) 
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your email address.' ; } 
  else  { $e = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $email ) ) ; }

  # Check password field.
  if ( empty( $pwd ) ) 
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your password.' ; } 
  else { $p = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $pwd ) ) ; }

  # On success retrieve user_id, first_name, and last name from 'users' database.
  if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
  {
    $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')" ;  
    $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) ;
    if ( @mysqli_num_rows( $r ) == 1 ) 
    {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ;
      return array( true, $row ) ; 
    }
    # Or on failure set error message.
    else { $errors[] = 'Email address and password not found.' ; }
  }
  # On failure retrieve error message/s.
  return array( false, $errors ) ; 
}
```

Comment: Give explanations where required. Dont just give the code.